# Reading then rewriting and modifying txt files

Tags: c, string, text

I need to read a txt file that contains my name, then create a new txt file that contains my name but spells it backwards ie(John Doe becomes Doe, John). My assignment says that I MAY need to create a temporary array to store the changed txt.

I'm getting the warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strchr' error. Ill include it into the code so you can see exactly where I'm receiving this warning.

Here is my code I feel as if I'm close. What am I doing wrong here? Please help me out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
FILE* txtFile=NULL;

txtFile=fopen("myName.txt", "r");

char myName [50]={'\0'};



if(txtFile==NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
}
else
{
    fgets(myName, sizeof(myName), txtFile);

    printf("%s\n", myName);
}

FILE* newTxtFile=NULL;

newTxtFile=fopen("myNewName.txt", "w+");

char newName[50]={'\0'};


if(newTxtFile==NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
}
else
{   
fgets(newName, sizeof(newName), newTxtFile);

fprintf(txtFile, "%s", newName);

rewind(newTxtFile);
//
char * space;
char *first=NULL;
char *last = NULL;
char *firstspace;
char *name=NULL;

name = myName;
//incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strchr'
firstspace=space=strchr(name,' ');

*firstspace='\0';

while (space!=NULL)
{
    last = space+1;
    space=strchr(space+1,' ');
}

printf("%s %s", last, name);

*firstspace=' ';
//
printf("text: %s \n", newName);
}
fclose(txtFile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it do that's `wrong`?

Comment: @JustinJasmann incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strchr' error.

Comment: Where? It would be useful to include this information in your post if there's a traceback

Comment: I did add it into the code

Comment: You need to `#include <string.h>` for `strchr`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Wow, I feel like an idiot

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to

The way you handle the output file is a little strange.

You should open it for output ("w");

Remove these 3 lines:

```
fgets(newName, sizeof(newName), newTxtFile);

fprintf(txtFile, "%s", newName);

rewind(newTxtFile);
```

Then add a line to print the output to the new file right next to where you print it on the screen:

```
fprintf(newTxtFile, "%s, %s", last, name);
```

And finally, in the beginning, add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to get the prototype for `strchr`.

That should do it!

Comment: It's not saving the edited txt to the new file though

Comment: My fprintf was trying to print to the input file. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was alot of useless junk in your code.

*The reason your new File has nothing is because **you are writing new data again in previous file**.*

Take a look here:

```
fprintf(txtFile, "%s", newName);



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
FILE* txtFile=NULL;

txtFile=fopen("helloWorld.txt", "r");

char myName [50]={'\0'};



if(txtFile==NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
}
else
{
    fgets(myName, sizeof(myName), txtFile);

    printf("%s\n", myName);
}

FILE* newTxtFile=NULL;

newTxtFile=fopen("myNewName.txt", "w+");

char newName[200]={'\0'};


if(newTxtFile==NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
}
else
{
fgets(newName, sizeof(newName), newTxtFile);


rewind(newTxtFile);
//
char * space;
char *first=NULL;
char *last = NULL;
char *firstspace;
char *name=NULL;

name = myName;
//incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strchr'
firstspace=space=strchr(name,' ');

*firstspace='\0';

while (space!=NULL)
{
    last = space+1;
    space=strchr(space+1,' ');
}

printf("%s %s", last, name);
/* my changes start here*/
strcat(newName,last);


strcat(newName," ");


strcat(newName,name);

printf("%s", newName);

fprintf(newTxtFile, "%s", newName);






}
fclose(txtFile);
fclose(newTxtFile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only thing wrong with this is that I don't need the name spelled backwards, I need the name spelled with the last name first then the first name. For example John Doe become Doe, John

Comment: @Jongware LOL yeah I saw it now. I hope SO makes restriction for users with <1000 rating that they could ask a new question only if non of the previous questions are un-accepted. Do you know a way to forward it to SO seniors?